Different xkb_options per keyboard layout in SwayWM
I've recently started learning to touch type after having used the "hunt and peck" style of typingy entire life. The layout I am using are different on both and I've configured SwayWM to switch between the 2 on a shortcut.
When I am touch typing, I've found certain key changes to be useful to me, for example switching the CTRL and the Caps Lock key however I don't need those changes when I switch back to my original hunt and Peck layout.
The issue I found is that the xkb_options setting seems to be decoupled from the keyboard layout setting, xkb_layout (an example of such a decoupling can be seen on the wiki), so whenever I switch layouts, the key changes are still there.
Is there any way to configure so whenever I switch layouts it also switches the settings configured in the xkb_options?
